# Ubuntu Upstart Failed To Start Permission Denied

Tags: python, ubuntu, permissions, upstart

I have an python app that I'm trying to run through an upstart script. Here is my conf file

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

respawn

setuid myuser
setgid myuser

chdir /home/myuser/

exec . bin/runapp
```

I am able to run the app without issue as the user from the command line but trying to start this upstart script fails with `start: Job failed to start`.

Looking in `/var/log/syslog` reveals:

```
localhost kernel: init: Failed to spawn myapp main process: unable to execute: Permission denied
```

This issue is very similar to the one described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65662/upstart-job-as-unprivileged-user-fails-with-permission-denied

All help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong...

`exec . bin/runapp` needed to be `exec ./bin/runapp`